# How can you delay alerts for Webview pages after loading?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function Links() { 
  function LoadingIndicatorView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.hubLoading}>
        <ActivityIndicator color='#009b88' size='large' />
      </View>
    )
  }

  const runFirst = 'window.alert("You will see this just before the webpage loads"); true;';
  const runAfterTenSecs = 'window.alert("You have been on this page for 10 seconds"); true;';

  return <WebView 
    source={{ uri: https://google.com }}
    renderLoading={LoadingIndicatorView}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    onMessage={() => {}}
    injectedJavaScript={runFirst}
  />;
}
```

`runAfterTenSecs` is currently unused. What changes can I make to it, or `runFirst`, that will produce the intended result of alerting "You have been on this page for 10 seconds" ten seconds after the Webview loads in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to delay the execution.

```js
window.alert("You will see this just before the webpage loads");
setTimeout(`window.alert("You have been on this page for 10 seconds")`, 10000);
```